# Is there an application that can mimic a physical Internet Radio?

Tags: internet-radio

I see some good reviews about some Internet Radios like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0032CNM4O), and some says you can listen to 12,000 channels world wide. (some even say 16,000 or 20,000 channels)   For the PC or Mac, is there such an app that can mimic what it does?  Usually, I find Internet Radio stations either on individual websites or on Windows Media Player, but never a central location that list all possible stations world wide which a physical Internet Radio might do (such as 11,000 channels)?

**Update: I tried both Windows Media Player in Windows 7 and the latest Winamp but none to them seem to be able to find a Taiwan or Taipei radio station...  I used the Internet instead, and found some webpage and it used to be playable only using IE, but now I am using Chrome and the radio plays as well... so I guess one good answer is: The Browser!**

Answer (score 1):

This looks like one of the best (17,000 stations)

http://www.radiosure.com/features/

There are many others, but a lot of them are either not free, or look like they could contain malware or adware.